# Grunt shell error on spaces in string

Tags: hadoop, gruntjs, apache-pig

I am trying to register a UDF jar in the Pig grunt shell (Pig 0.13.0). The register statement below errors due to what I believe is the space in the path:

```
register '/home/hadoop/Eclipse Projects/pigudfs/target/pigudfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar';
```

The following error is generated:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <QUOTEDSTRING> "\'/home/hadoop/Eclipse Projects/pigudfs/target/pigudfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\' "" at line 7, column 10
```

I have tried an array of options to try to escape the space without any luck...

Comment: Did you try relative path? In my case I have folder `params` with pig script and folder `lib` with UDF. REGISTER command than looks like this - `REGISTER lib/piggybank.jar`; Or you can try to add your file into different folder (without spaces) and use register command without quotes.

Comment: I haven't tried relative path, but it would still require the space. I guess I can move this into a directory so that the path does not contain a space but I have been avoiding doing so for a number of reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
 give the path name without the single quotes,

like

```
register home/hadoop/Eclipse Projects/pigudfs/target/pigudfs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

Comment: Gave it a shot. Didn't work. Tried to add a backslash to escape the the space, no luck.

Comment: add \ between Eclipse Projects like Eclipse\Projects, then try